# Host a ASP.Net MVC3 application on my own 2008 server with IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

This seems to be so easy that it is documented nowhere.... I have finished my first MVC3 project and now I want to host it on my own IIS7 (W2008) server. How is it done?

Comment: that on how you want to deply - there is a deployment option in VS2010 you could use... it can also depend on things like dependencies (needed DLLs etc.) and permissions/rights... to help you need to give some more details... have you tried anything ? if yes, what didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to install get MVC running on Windows 7 Professional or greater. For Windows Server 2008, please see [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2/) link. The IIS management component should be the same for Windows 7 / Server 2008. The install process will be a little different.

Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on of off

Expand Internet Information Services and check off all that you need (FTP, World Wide Web)

Specifically I use FTP (FTP Service), and WWW Services with Application Development (.NET Extensibility, ASP, ASP.NET, ISAPI Extensions, and ISAPI Filters) enabled. Under security you should at least enable Basic Authentication.

After this is done, go to [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) to get the Web Platform Installer, which will allow you to easily install .NET 3.5/4.0, MVC, and other features you might need such as MS SQL Express.

Once this is done, go to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services Managger

Expand COMPUTERNAME, expand sites, right click Default Web Site (unless you want to use a different folder, if so, right click sites and click "Add New"), whichever site you choose, you can right click and choose "Add FTP Publishing". From there just follow the prompts, and allow access to whichever users you want. Now you can FTP in from Microsoft visual Studio 2010 (Using Publish).

In Visual Studio - right click the MVC application you want to publish, go to Publish, enter the ftp site settings (most likely ftp://localhost if its a local install), user, password, and whether or not to replace or delete files. You can save this profile so you don't have to re-enter this information every time.

This question/answer might even be more geared toward serverfault, or superuser, not sure? If so I'm sure it will be moved.

Comment: If everyone would open up Google and search before asking questions, then we would have less clutter. No offense to the OP - I'm sure he has googled around. I will post an updated answer that should help.

Comment: Google answers are particularly frowned upon here.  In fact, the let me gooogle that for you site is a keyword blacklist here.  You may think there's clutter here, but I tend to think of it as a google without non-programming results.  Everything programming related should be here in one form or another, so long as it's a question/answer.

Comment: Noted, removed the "google this" portion of my answer as it is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Don't forget the folder permissions for the App_Data folder... But thanks!

Comment: Hrm can you elaborate? I had no permissions issues with App_Data that I can remember

Answer (score 3):

There are two options. If you have control of the server and can install on it, the easiest is to install the [ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4211) on it and then install and configure the MVC app as any other web application.

If the runtime cannot be installed on the server, option called [Bin Deployment](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) can be used.